# Is there a way to get a list of all PDB IDs for proteins with crystal structure information?

Tags: pdb

I would like to download all the PDB files which have crystal structure information in them. But the query builder seems to require me to enter the PDB IDs manually.

Is there a way to get a list of those PDB IDs at RCSB PDB?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the links. Very useful indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Comment migrated as answer as it inadvertently may have been an answer.

If the sole records in a PDB file that are of interest are `EXPDTA`,`CRYST1` ORIGX1``,`ORIGX2`, `ORIGX3`,`SCALE1`,`SCALE2`,`SCALE3`, the in the [FTP site](http://wwpdb.org/ftp/pdb-ftp-sites) the file ftp.wwpdb.org/pub/pdb/derived_data/index/crystal.idx  contains this information in a tabular format.

If an extra piece of metadata is sought, such as **some of** the refinement details in `REMARK` lines, then [the PDBe API can help](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/api/doc/). In particular, the `experiment` entrypoint ([example](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/api/pdb/entry/experiment/451c)) is of interest.

Answer (score 2):

running the query builder at RCS PDB against id with space group (so crystal info) I get:

[image: 172456 hits]

more about RCSB PDB web services here: https://www.rcsb.org/docs/programmatic-access/web-services-overview

and the search API here: https://search.rcsb.org/index.html#search-api  think you should query for entries where `symmetry.pdbx_full_space_group_name_H_M` exists (https://search.rcsb.org/structure-search-attributes.html and ask to have returned entry.id (a list of in this case)